# How to prevent hitting the enter to submit if textbox is blank

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.mypage.com/search.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
    <input name="ctl00$centerContent$txtSearchPhysician" id="ctl00_centerContent_txtSearchPhysician" type="text" size="25" />
    <input name="ctl00$centerContent$btnPhysicianSearch" id="ctl00_centerContent_btnPhysicianSearch" type=button value="Search" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input[id="ctl00_centerContent_txtSearchPhysician"]').keyup(function() {
        var raw_text =  jQuery(this).val();
        var return_text = raw_text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,'');
        jQuery(this).val(return_text);
    });

    jQuery('input[id="ctl00_centerContent_txtSearchPhysician"]').keydown(function(e) {
        jQuery(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    });

    jQuery('input[id="ctl00_centerContent_btnPhysicianSearch"]').click(function() {
        var raw_text =  jQuery('input[id="ctl00_centerContent_txtSearchPhysician"]').val();
        if (!raw_text) {
            alert ('Search Query is Blank');
            jQuery('input[id="ctl00_centerContent_txtSearchPhysician"]').css('background-color', '#FF3333');
            jQuery('input[id="ctl00_centerContent_txtSearchPhysician"]').focus();
        }
        if (raw_text) {
            //alert (raw_text); //displays the search string
            //document.location.href="http://www.google.com"; //redirects to google.com
            window.document.cookie='postbackcookie=';
            window.document.location.href="http://www.mypage.com?searchtext=" + raw_text;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Almost everything is working fine except one thing. If the textbox has the focus and I hit enter without entering anything it just reloads the "action" page.

How do I modify the code so, when the above happens, The textbox background turns red and the enter is nulled. The only time enter will work in the textbox is if there is a string already there?

Comment: You should change the jquery selectors from jQuery('input[id="ctl00_centerContent_txtSearchPhysician"]') to $('#ctl00_centerContent_txtSearchPhysician'), there is no reason to specify the type of input since you are using unique ids.

Comment: You can use event.preventDefault() on the button click event in case the value of the textbox is empty string.

Comment: The button click is working fine. I am just having an issue with the pressing enter in the textbox :/

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you using location.href instead of setting your form type to GET and properly naming your text input to what url param you wanted to go to the url on the action page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intercept the submit event and validate the form before allowing the submit to take place.

```
$("#aspnetForm").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ( $("#someinput").val() != "" ) {
        this.submit(); // this doesn't trigger another submit event
    }
})
```

By doing it this way, it would be easy to later add more validation as needed.

Comment: It just reloads the page :/

Comment: that doesn't make sense. You did modify it to point at your input correct? my selector is obviously just an example. The form id also has to be correct.

Comment: i fixed it... instead of the `form.submit();` I added the code from the `if (raw_text)` block and its working :) I up voted and accepted.

Comment: Not to mention, you should move the logic from your button click into this submit event handler. The button click event handler is no longer needed with this submit handler.

Answer (score 1):

add this to the input: `required`

```
<input name="ctl00$centerContent$btnPhysicianSearch" id="ctl00_centerContent_btnPhysicianSearch" type=button value="Search" required/>
```

Comment: Try using required="required", it might make older browsers like it better.